# any workaround to add token authorization decorator to endpoint at swagger python server stub

Tags: python, flask, swagger, connexion

I know how to secure endpoint in flask, and I want to do the same thing to swagger generated python server stub. I am wondering how I can integrate flask token authentication works for the swagger python server, so the endpoint will be secured. I could easily add token authentication decorator to endpoint in flask. This is how things works in flask-restplus and this one below is totally working:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)

authorizations = {
    'apikey' : {
        'type' : 'apiKey',
        'in' : 'header',
        'name' : 'X-API-KEY'
    },
}

api = Api(app, security = 'apikey',authorizations=authorizations)

def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None
        if 'X-API-KEY' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['X-API-KEY']
        if not token:
            return {'message' : 'Token is missing.'}, 401
        if token != 'mytoken':
            return {'message' : 'Your token is wrong, wrong, wrong!!!'}, 401
        print('TOKEN: {}'.format(token))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated


 class classResource(Resource):
    @api.doc(security='apikey')
    @token_required
    def get(self):
        return "this is test"
```

**how to make Bearer Authentication at swagger generated server stub**:

I am wondering how am I gonna integrate this authentication to swagger generated python server stub. Here is how spec file begins:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
    title: test api
    version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1/
  description: Example API Service
paths:
    /about:
        get:
            summary: general summary
            description: get current version
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: About information
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/version'
                '401':
                    description: Authorization information is missing or invalid.
components:
    securitySchemes:
        BearerAuth:
            scheme: bearer
            type: http
security:
    - BearerAuth: []
```

**controller at swagger python server stub**:

**update: my new attempt**:

here is default_controller that generated by swagger python server stub and I tried as follow:

```
import connexion
import six

@api.doc(security='apikey')
@token_required
def about_get():  # noqa: E501
    return 'do some magic!'
```

but `authorize` button is missing. why?

in swagger python server stub, I have also `authorization_controller` which has following code logic:

```
from typing import List

def check_BearerAuth(token):
    return {'test_key': 'test_value'}
```

**update**:

here in swagger python server stub. `about_get()` is one endpoint and it is not secured right now. How can we secured that like what we did in flask? any thought?

how can I add above flask token authentication to `about_get()` in swagger python server stub? Is there any way of doing this? any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Here is a example yaml to use JWT as bearer format:
https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/master/examples/openapi3/jwt/openapi.yaml

After you generate the flask server, on the swagger-ui you can find the 'Authorize' button. And if you execute /secret before 'Authorize' you will get a 401 error.

So for your situation, you have to change it into:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
    title: test api
    version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1/
  description: Example API Service
paths:
    /about:
        get:
            summary: general summary
            description: get current version
            security:
            - jwt: ['secret']
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: About information
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                type: string


components:
  securitySchemes:
    jwt:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
      x-bearerInfoFunc: app.decode_token
```

Hence, after you have installed `connexion[swagger-ui]` and start the server by `python -m swagger_server`. Then, navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/ui/`, you can test the auth works properly. If you call the `/about` before authorize, it will hit a 401 error.

---

To add auth from code:

```
from flask_restx import Api
authorizations = {
    'Bearer Auth': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    },
}
api = Api(app, security='Bearer Auth', authorizations=authorizations)
```

Btw, better migrate the flask_restplus into flask_restx, as flask_restplus is no longer be maintained.

**Source**

https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/398#issuecomment-444336893

Comment: what you are showing works for flask api. what I am trying to do is sdo same thing on swagger generated server stub like this one: [swagger generated python server](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/tree/master/openapi/photo_album/codegen_server) ? how do you do that?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Let me look into it.

Comment: what you showed is exactly what I tried and worked for my flask app. but now I generated python server stub using swagger and want to secure endpoint at [swagger python server](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/tree/master/openapi/photo_album/codegen_server). that's the main question actually. thanks R.yan!

Comment: any possible updated attempt how to secure endpoint in swagger python server? can we inject token authentication decorator that worked in flask to `about_get()` in swagger python server? any idea?

Comment: @R.yan I think your posted answer is not what kim asked, so I down voted for now. kim already showed token authentication. I think he is trying to make flask token authentication functional in swagger python server stub which used `connexion`.

Comment: @jyson, yes, I know. I'm investigating the problem too.

Comment: @kim, I've updated the answer above, please check:)

Comment: @R.yan I think I should rephrase my question clearly in another post, so let me accept your answer. Thanks and please give your attention new version this post if you can. Thanks R.yan

Comment: @R.yan, I understood it to some extent, but I am unable to understand what does the 'secret' represent in the line:  jwt: ['secret'] in the YAML file, for the endpoint /about. Can you point me to a helpful article which explains the 'secret' attribute or keyword?