# No adding of token in swagger for flask

Tags: python, flask, swagger

This is my code:

```
authorizations = {
    'Basic Auth': {
        'type': 'basic',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    },
}
task_namespace = Namespace('task', security='Authorization', authorizations=authorizations, description='A namespace for tasks')
@task_namespace.route('/')
class TaskGetResource(Resource):
    @jwt_required(refresh=True)
    def get(self):
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        return Task.query.filter_by(
                user_id=user_id
            )
```

WHen I run the flask app and go to the swagger url, I authorize it by email and password and then run the `api/task` as located in the swagger, but the header token does not get added

Complete code is https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/flask-tasks-jwt

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the "lock" icon?

Comment: NO i do see the lock icon and I unlock it. It works. But the api that I want to test still doesnot have the bearer token when I `try it out`

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: I believe you actually want `security="Basic Auth"`, not `security='Authorization'`.

Comment: I am afraid it didnt work also

Comment: Added a github link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the the code as follows after going through this video:

```
authorizations = {
'jsonWebToken': {
    'type': 'apiKey',
    'in': 'header',
    'name': 'Authorization'
},
}
task_namespace = Namespace(
    'task',
    authorizations=authorizations
)

@task_namespace.route('/')
class TaskGetResource(Resource):
    @task_namespace.doc(security="jsonWebToken")
    @jwt_required()
    def get(self):
        ....
```

Answer (score -1):

The security parameter only works with the `flask_restx.Api` class and not with `flask_restx.Namespace` class.

So, the best alternative for your use case will be adding this security parameter in the **@api.doc()** decorator.

You can do that by changing your task.py file as follows:

```
authorizations = {
    'Basic': {
        'type': 'basic'
    },
}
task_namespace = Namespace('task', authorizations=authorizations, description='A namespace for tasks')

...


@task_namespace.route('/')
@task_namespace.doc(security="Basic")
class TaskGetResource(Resource):
    ...
```

I hope this helps!

### EDIT

You are using "basic" authentication type here - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/basic-authentication/

This means that the token will be passed as "Authorization header that contains the Basic word followed by a space and a base64-encoded username:password string"

If you want to implement custom authentication with swagger, you will need to use openapi 3.0, and specify the details in yml file as shown here - [any workaround to add token authorization decorator to endpoint at swagger python server stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855161/any-workaround-to-add-token-authorization-decorator-to-endpoint-at-swagger-pytho)

Comment: Token is added. But I get the message `{
  "msg": "Missing 'Bearer' type in 'Authorization' header. Expected 'Authorization: Bearer <JWT>'"
}`

Comment: @EchchamaNayak I have added some edits to answer this. I hope it helps.

Comment: ok i think my use case would be better off with basic auth. should i remove jwt required?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak Yes, you can create a basic auth checker for that decoding. You should find some helpful resource in the documentation of Open API for that too.